# Apache Isis jdoqlFromClause validation error with multi-level inheritance

Tags: java, validation, inheritance, isis

I've just upgraded Apache Isis to the latest version 1.14.0 in my project and faced with the next problem: 
1) I have 3 domain objects with **multi-level** inheritance (in the same package): A, B, C

```
@DomainObject(objectType = "A", editing = Editing.ENABLED)
public abstract class A

@DomainObject(objectType = "B", editing = Editing.ENABLED)
public class B extends A

@DomainObject(objectType = "C", editing = Editing.ENABLED)
public class C extends B
```

2) class A has the following JDOQL query:

```
@Queries({
        @Query(
                name = "getById",
                value = "SELECT "
                        + "FROM com.home.test.A "
                        + "WHERE id == :id")
      })
```

3) When I turned on the validation:

```
isis.reflector.validator.jdoqlFromClause=true
```

I've got the error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Metamodel is invalid: 
com.home.test.C: error in JDOQL query, class name after FROM clause should be same as class name on which annotated, or one of its supertypes (JDOQL : SELECT FROM com.home.test.A WHERE id == :id)
```

4)If I make **one-level** inheritance:

```
@DomainObject(objectType = "A", editing = Editing.ENABLED)
public abstract class A

@DomainObject(objectType = "B", editing = Editing.ENABLED)
public class B extends A

@DomainObject(objectType = "C", editing = Editing.ENABLED)
public class C extends A
```

The validation passes OK.

Please help to pass jdoqlFromClause validation with multi-level inheritance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, so, this needs to be improved I think.  Thanks for writing this up.

Could you raise a defect on our [JIRA](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ISIS), please?

Thx
Dan

Comment: Thank you, Dan! [ISIS-1631](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ISIS-1631) created.